# Obtener nombre de un Dato mediante su ID

Tags: mysql

Disculpen una consulta quisiera que en la tabla "Datos" hay una columna llamado "Nombre" y lo que quiero hacer es obtener el nombre correspondiente al id de la columna "ID_datos"

Tabla "datos"

[image: Tabla "Datos"] los ID_datos son id de los cuestionarios que estoy realizando

Los id de la columna "ID_datos" de la tabla "datos" se extraen de la tabla "posts" de la columna "ID" (se extrajo mediante una consulta de trigger) y el nombre del cuesionario esta en la columna "post_title"

Tabla "post"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como realizo esa consulta soy novato :c

ACTUALIZACION 1

ya pude crear un join

```
SELECT ID_datos,post_title FROM datos 
JOIN wp_posts  ON ID = ID_datos;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero quisiera hacerlo automáticamente así como un trigger, alguien me podría ayudar en ese paso o explicarme xfavor

ACTUALIZACION 2

Quiero hacer un TIGGER algo parecido a esto (el del ejemplo de abajo me da error)
Entonces crear un TRIGGER + JOIN

```
     CREATE TRIGGER `join` 
        AFTER INSERT ON `wp_posts`
        FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
            SELECT ID_datos,post_title FROM datos JOIN wp_posts  ON ID = ID_datos;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Con `INNER JOIN` puedes unir una o varias tablas. [Aquí va el tutorial](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx), luego intenta tu código y si hay problemas te ayudaremos.

Comment: okey, ya logre hacer el join, pero quiero hacerlo como un trigguer o que se actualice automáticamente

Comment: un trigger donde??? que se actualize que cosa automaticamente?

Comment: igual no tiene mucho sentido que tengas una tabla que solamente tenga exactamente 2 columnas que estan en otra... cual es el punto???

Comment: Es que es un proyecto de Wordpress para no hacerlo muy largo los nombre se almacena en post_title y quiero utilizar varias veces la columna post_title en una sola consulta, y me da un error al poner mas de 1 vez esa columna

Comment: Como te dije en una anterior pregunta, debes usar `NEW` o `OLD`, según el caso, para referirte a la tabla que está disparando el `TRIGGER`. O sea, si `wp_posts` dispara el `TRIGGER` y es un `AFTER INSERT` entonces debes usar `NEW.laColumnaDewp_posts` ... OJO: prueba bien tu `TRIGGER` antes de lanzarlo a producción. Un `TRIGGER` mal programado te puede crear un desastre en los datos.

Comment: si lo utilizare, pero la estructura para el TRIGGER y JOIN no se si este bien. porque en si la consulta de JOIN esta bien

Comment: Más que "como un trigger" creo que lo que deseas es [crear una vista](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) si es para consultar un dato. Si es para insertarlo, entonces una de dos: o no vas a cumplir las [formas normales](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos) de una base de datos o bien puedes hacerlo con un iniciador, como deseas, pero vas a duplicar datos y crear inconsistencia cuando modifiques un nombre en la tabla ajena.

Comment: no se entiende el punto de todo esto.. como te dijeron, suena a que queres una vista.. y esto "me da un error al poner mas de 1 vez esa columna" se resuelve facil en sql.. se hace asi: select campo1 as nombre1, campo1 as nombre2, campo1 as nombre3...